# My MainForm refresh is erroring

Tags: c#, winforms

When selecting refreshBtn_Click it should be refreshing the MainForm (which is its current form).

> Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Refresh()'

```
    private void AddAdminBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainForm.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: ``this.Refresh()``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code isn't very clear

but the obvious answer is that the object MainForm is not set to a value
if you want to call a function on the current form then you can use the self reference of "this" (the vb equivalent is me) as the this object is always the current instance

```
private void AddAdminBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Refresh();
}
```

or a second option is to allow the object to decide the target with out a explicit instruction, this is done in the following order

- local variables
- this
- static
- namespaces

so as long as you don't have a local action called Refresh then it will default to the forms Refresh action
so

```
private void AddAdminBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Refresh();
}
```